# Why does Typescript give this error? Generic indexed type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got this generic type:

```js
type MapToFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: (x: T[K]) => void;
};
```

It works fine in this case:

```js
type T1 = { a: string };

const fnmap1: MapToFunctions<T1> = {
  a: (x: string) => {
    console.log(x);
  },
}
```

I can even leave out the type of `x`, and TypeScript correctly infers that it's a string.

But if I add an index signature to the type used as the parameter, it doesn't work anymore:

```js
type T2 = {
  a: string;
  [key: string]: unknown;
}

const fnmap2: MapToFunctions<T2> = {
  a: (x: string) => {
    console.log(x);
  },
}
```

On `fnmap2` I get this error:

```
Type '{ a: (x: string) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'MapToFunctions<T2>'.
  Property 'a' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(x: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(x: unknown) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Why does this error happen? It seems pretty obvious that property `a` should have type `(x: string) => void`. In fact, TypeScript seems to agree; if I leave out the type annotation for argument `x`, TypeScript infers that it is a string... but then still gives the same error!

Answer (score 0):

While typing up this question, I think I've pretty much figured it out, although I'd still appreciate a more definitive and/or intuitive answer.

Type `MapToFunctions<T2>` is equivalent to:

```js
{
  a: (x: string) => void;
  [key: string]: (x: unknown) => void;
}
```

which is actually not a legal type.

Adding an index signature `[key: string]: Type` to an object type doesn't mean "all the *other* string-keyed properties have type Type". It means "*all* string-keyed properties have type Type". For this to work, the types of all the explicitly declared properties have to be compatible with type `Type`.

It's always ok to add `[key: string]: unknown`, because every type is a subtype of `unknown`; that is, `Type extends unknown` is true for every `Type`. But in the above type, `(x: string) => void` is not a subtype of `(x: unknown) => void` (in fact it's the other way around). So the type is self-contradictory.

I found a pretty good fix for the problem. My new definition of `MapToFunctions` is:

```js
type MapToFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : K]?: (x: T[K]) => void;
};
```

The extra manipulation inside the index signature means that only the explicitly declared properties of type `T` are carried over into the resulting type; any `[key: string]: Type` properties are removed. So `MapToFunctions<T2>` is now equivalent to

```js
{
  a: (x: string) => void;
}
```

and there's no contradiction. I guess there would be a problem if I actually needed those indexed properties, but I don't. (Of course this is all extremely simplified compared with my actual code).

Fully understanding the new definition of `MapToFunctions` is left as an exercise for the reader.